# How to deploy EMR Terraform using terraform, a simple out of the box working example

Tags: apache-spark, terraform, amazon-emr

I am using
Terraform v0.14.5
And trying the official [Terraform example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/emr_cluster)
With its specified versioning:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.25.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}
```

After "solving" a few obvious bugs

changing: from allow_all  to allow_access (the name of the security group)

```
aws_security_group.allow_access.id
```

changing: from allow_all  to allow_access (the name of the security group)

making cidr_blocks a list

updating the emr version

```
aws_security_group.allow_access.id

cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.cidr_block]

release_label = "emr-6.2.0"
```

I managed to init and plan but failed at apply

```
Error: Error waiting for EMR Cluster state to be "WAITING" or "RUNNING": TERMINATING: BOOTSTRAP_FAILURE: Master instance (i-07e34ac1b04ebde01) failed attempting to download bootstrap action 1 file from S3
```

The bug seems to arise from:

```
  bootstrap_action {
    path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if"
    name = "runif"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]
  }
```

so I downloaded the file

```
aws s3 cp s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if .
```

and added it locally:

```
  bootstrap_action {
    path = "file://${path.module}/run-if"
//    path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if"

    name = "runif"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]
  }
```

This is the entire code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.25.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = "emr-test-arn"
  release_label = "emr-6.2.0"
  applications  = ["Spark", "Zeppelin"]

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id                         = aws_subnet.main.id
    emr_managed_master_security_group = aws_security_group.allow_access.id
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = aws_security_group.allow_access.id
    instance_profile                  = aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn
  }

  master_instance_group {
    instance_type = "m5.xlarge"
  }

  core_instance_group {
    instance_count = 1
    instance_type  = "m5.xlarge"
  }

  tags = {
    role     = "rolename"
    dns_zone = "env_zone"
    env      = "env"
    name     = "name-env"
  }

  bootstrap_action {
//    path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if"
    path = "file://${path.module}/run-if"
    name = "runif"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]
  }

  configurations_json = <<EOF
  [
    {
      "Classification": "hadoop-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    },
    {
      "Classification": "spark-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    }
  ]
EOF

  service_role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.arn
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_access" {
  name        = "allow_access"
  description = "Allow inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_subnet.main]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      ingress,
      egress,
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    name = "emr_test"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block           = "168.31.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    name = "emr_test"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "168.31.0.0/20"

  tags = {
    name = "emr_test"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "r" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_main_route_table_association" "a" {
  vpc_id         = aws_vpc.main.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.r.id
}

###

# IAM Role setups

###

# IAM role for EMR Service
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_emr_service_role" {
  name = "iam_emr_service_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "iam_emr_service_policy" {
  name = "iam_emr_service_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:DeleteTags",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
            "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
            "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
            "ec2:DetachVolume",
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:GetRolePolicy",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:ListRolePolicies",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*",
            "sdb:BatchPutAttributes",
            "sdb:Select",
            "sqs:CreateQueue",
            "sqs:Delete*",
            "sqs:GetQueue*",
            "sqs:PurgeQueue",
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
        ]
    }]
}
EOF
}

# IAM Role for EC2 Instance Profile
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_emr_profile_role" {
  name = "iam_emr_profile_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "emr_profile" {
  name = "emr_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_profile_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "iam_emr_profile_policy" {
  name = "iam_emr_profile_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_profile_role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:*",
            "dynamodb:*",
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "elasticmapreduce:Describe*",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListBootstrapActions",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListClusters",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListInstanceGroups",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListInstances",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListSteps",
            "kinesis:CreateStream",
            "kinesis:DeleteStream",
            "kinesis:DescribeStream",
            "kinesis:GetRecords",
            "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
            "kinesis:MergeShards",
            "kinesis:PutRecord",
            "kinesis:SplitShard",
            "rds:Describe*",
            "s3:*",
            "sdb:*",
            "sns:*",
            "sqs:*"
        ]
    }]
}
EOF
}
```

Can anyone recommend a working example or help sort out the VPC bug?

Comment: Can you show the actuall code that you are trying to use to deplou EMR?

Comment: @Marcin I just added the entire code.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out I have a new version of terraform CLI namely 14.5 which dosn't work with most examples on the web. So for the non initiated (People without idiosyncratic knowledge of versions ...) I'm adding a specific "recepie" of how to get an up and running cluster.

I used  https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-emr-cluster.git
because it appeared first and was continuously maintained. Bare in mind that it uses many remote modules and although they are on Github they have version dependancies and maintaining them is a challenge in and of itself. Also bare in mind that this is just a "Hello World" as far as I am concerned.

- Install tfswitch.
  On mac:

```
brew install tfswitch

tfswitch 0.13.5
```

- clone the repo, cd inside and init.
  Mine worked with this specific commit: ed81e4259ae66178e6cbb7dcea75596f1701fe61, so if you need to check it out so you can have a sane starting point.

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-emr-cluster.git
cd /terraform-aws-emr-cluster/examples/complete/
terraform init
```

This will download sources from Github

- configure variables by copying and editing the file:

```
cp fixtures.us-east-2.tfvars terraform.tfvars
```

- create a secrets directory and make sure the path is configured to it

```
mkdir <path of your choice>secrets

ssh_public_key_path = <path of your choice>secrets
```

- provision EMR cluster:

```
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

This should produce an EMR cluster.

P.S.

all I wanted was a POC to test out a solution for architecture. something that took me 20 minutes in the past has become very complex and challenging for the uninitiated. It would seem that the principals of infrastructure as code, declarative code, simplicity, clean code and simple sanity are compromised by the idiosyncrasy of DevOps Babylon Tower and security.